# How to add one year to timestamp in Tarantool 1.8 using SQL?

Tags: sql, datetime, timestamp, tarantool

As I see in [documentation](https://tarantool.org/doc/1.8/tutorials/sql_tutorial.html#temporal-functions),

I can add one year to any date using datetime() function:

```
SELECT datetime('2014-01-23 12:33:34', '1 year')
```

Result is `2015-01-23 12:33:34`.

But I have timestamp in column (int value), for example `1390466014`. 
When I try to add year to this timestamp using datetime() function I obtain `null` instead of `1422005614` in result:

```
SELECT datetime(1390466014, '1 year')  -- null
```

How to add one year to timestamp to obtain new timestamp? Does Tarantool have any functions for working with timestamps?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that Tarantool 1.8.1 is storing and handling datetime as strings. So, if you want to use Unix time, just say thart explicitly, like that:

```
tarantool> SELECT datetime(datetime(1390466014, 'unixepoch'), '1 year')
---
- - ['2015-01-23 08:33:34']
...
```